# display fields if not empty in PHP/YII

Tags: php, yii

I used to code with Groovy ... I found that this 'feature' (no idea what they called it) so fun n nice (I heard they implemented this on C# too).

for example ... I want to display person neighbour name

I just type

```
println person?.neigbour?.name ;
```

it means if the neighbour is empty / blank .. it didn't display anything .

how to do this in php 5/yii?

example:

instead of typing long codes like 
     
'/>

Would it be better to type like 
'/>

Comment: If you want solution in PHP, show example code in PHP. In general there are some functions like `isset` or `empty`, but I don't think there's suck cool syntax as in your example.

Comment: isset isn't working for you?

Comment: no ... i want simple syntax if php has ... 
for example: (just to show ... not the correct syntax of php since I have no idea whether the php has the operator or not)

<input type='text' name='neighbourName' value='<?php echo $person?.neighbour?.name;?>'/>

if I have to check all the object before displaying the name ... it would be long...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first place I think this is no Yii issue, but simply PHP. Assuming, that you use Yii with nice models, there it would go sth like this:

```
if($person && $person->neighbour && !empty($person->neighbour->name))  {
   echo $person->neighbour->name;
}
```

a shortcut for this may be (not so nice):

```
echo $person ? ($person->neighbour ? ($person->neighbour->name ? $person->neighbour->name : "" ) : ""  ) : "";
```

Answer (score 1):

use `empty()`
check:

```
if(!empty($variable))
{
//show fields here
}
```